# Computer Vision Quickstart not working for Java

Tags: java, azure, computer-vision

I am new to computer vision and I am trying to implement the following ([example](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-quickstart-code/blob/master/java/ComputerVision/src/main/java/ComputerVisionQuickstart.java)), but it always sends me the same error:

> Something went wrong: Couldn't extract the operation id from the
> operation location

```
/**
 * OCR with READ : Performs a Read Operation on a local image
 * @param client instantiated vision client
 * @param localFilePath local file path from which to perform the read operation against
 */
private static void ReadFromFile(ComputerVisionClient client) {
    System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------");
    
    String localFilePath = "C:\\main\\resources\\file.pdf";
    System.out.println("Read with local file: " + localFilePath);


    try {
        File rawImage = new File(localFilePath);
        byte[] localImageBytes = Files.readAllBytes(rawImage.toPath());

        // Cast Computer Vision to its implementation to expose the required methods
        ComputerVisionImpl vision = (ComputerVisionImpl) client.computerVision();

        // Read in remote image and response header
        ReadInStreamHeaders responseHeader =
                vision.readInStreamWithServiceResponseAsync(localImageBytes, null, null)
                    .toBlocking()
                    .single()
                    .headers();
   
        String operationLocation = responseHeader.operationLocation();
        System.out.println("Operation Location:" + operationLocation);

        getAndPrintReadResult(vision, operationLocation);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
/**
 * Polls for Read result and prints results to console
 * @param vision Computer Vision instance
 * @return operationLocation returned in the POST Read response header
 */
private static void getAndPrintReadResult(ComputerVision vision, String operationLocation) throws InterruptedException {
    System.out.println("Polling for Read results ...");

    // Extract OperationId from Operation Location
    String operationId = extractOperationIdFromOpLocation(operationLocation);

    boolean pollForResult = true;
    ReadOperationResult readResults = null;

    while (pollForResult) {
        // Poll for result every second
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        readResults = vision.getReadResult(UUID.fromString(operationId));

        // The results will no longer be null when the service has finished processing the request.
        if (readResults != null) {
            // Get request status
            OperationStatusCodes status = readResults.status();

            if (status == OperationStatusCodes.FAILED || status == OperationStatusCodes.SUCCEEDED) {
                pollForResult = false;
            }
        }
    }
  
    // Print read results, page per page
    for (ReadResult pageResult : readResults.analyzeResult().readResults()) {
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Printing Read results for page " + pageResult.page());
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        for (Line line : pageResult.lines()) {
            builder.append(line.text());
            builder.append("\n");
        }

        System.out.println(builder.toString());
    }
}


//The error marks it in this method since it cannot extract the operation id


 /**
 * Extracts the OperationId from a Operation-Location returned by the POST Read operation
 * @param operationLocation
 * @return operationId
 */
private static String extractOperationIdFromOpLocation(String operationLocation) {
    if (operationLocation != null && !operationLocation.isEmpty()) {
        String[] splits = operationLocation.split("/");

        if (splits != null && splits.length > 0) {
            return splits[splits.length - 1];
        }
    }
    throw new IllegalStateException("Something went wrong: Couldn't extract the operation id from the operation location");
}
```

I would appreciate if you could help me see what my mistake is or what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Please edit your question to include specifics. As written, you didn't include any code, any specific area of the code that throws this error, inputs and outputs, etc. You only included a link to an external repo, which would require someone to go there, clone the repo, go through the entire example, and attempt to recreate your error, not knowing anything about how you set things up. Please provide as much detail as needed to help others help you.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I already edited the question, I hope it is understandable

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you only follows one part from the quickstart. Before that, you should also set up the environment and set up your main method, subscription ID and keys. Please follow the whole document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/computer-vision/quickstarts-sdk/client-library?tabs=visual-studio&pivots=programming-language-java

Comment: I have implemented the whole example, I put those methods since it is in the part where it throws me the error

Something went wrong: Couldn't extract the operation id from the operation location

specifically in the method extractOperationIdFromOpLocation

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71708456/how-can-can-i-solve-couldnt-extract-the-operation-id-from-the-operation-locati